# WCF Data Services: Mocking OperationContext

Tags: wcf-data-services

We would like to mock the `OperationContext` class for testing purposes. We are using 'Mock'. But `OperationContext` is a sealed class and cannot be mocked. Therefore we are trying to create a dummy `OperationContext` object. But `OperationContext` constructor takes `IContextChannel` as parameter. We would like to know of a way to get hold of a `IContextChannel` so that it can be passed to the `OperationContext` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The general recommendation is to [implement wcf services without referencing wcf](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/06/26/implementing-wcf-services-without-referencing-wcf.aspx).

Examples how to do it are in http://marcin.floryan.pl/blog/2012/01/do-we-really-need-wcfmock

> We replaced a reference to OperationContext with a reference to
>   operationResponse. The operationResponse should be defined as an
>   interface and can be injected in the constructor just like the
>   repository is in the example given. Our test method now becomes
>   slightly shorter and more readable.

And  in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/12/04/integrationtestingwcfservices.aspx

> Let's, for a moment, consider the need to perform authorization. You
>   could inspect OperationContext.Current directly in each of your
>   operation implementations, but that would be mixing concerns (business
>   logic implemented in the operation mixed together with authorization).
>   The correct way would be to provide a class deriving from
>   ServiceAuthorizationManager, and configure the service to use this
>   class for authorization. This would allow you to keep unit testing
>   your operation implementations, but obviously, you also need to test
>   the authorization manager itself, and it turns out that integration
>   testing is the easiest way to accomplish this task.

If you still need mock follow a recommendation from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/06/28/unit-testing-duplex-wcf-services.aspx

> All you have to do is to replace the call
>   toOperationContext.GetCallbackChannel with something abstract. On
>   .NET 3.5, the easiest abstraction is Func, which has the same
>   signature, but if you are on .NET 3.0, you can always define a similar
>   delegate type of your own.

Alternatively as a last recourse  you can use [WCFmock](http://wcfmock.codeplex.com/)

```
#if DEBUG
     using WebOperationContext = System.ServiceModel.Web.MockedWebOperationContext;
#endif
```

> This is useful for instance, if you want to use the mocked version in
>   development, and always the WCF version in production. That's all, you
>   do not need to touch your existing service implementation at all, once
>   you defined that alias, the service is ready to be tested

From http://blog.gfader.com/2010/08/how-to-unit-test-wcf-service.html

> all your calls to OperationContext.Current.Channel.SessionId get
>   intercepted by MockedOperationContext, but only in your tests you are
>   mocking the OperationContext. In your normal environment that
>   MockedOperationContext acts as a proxy to the real OperationContext.

Answer (score 0):

The [NetFX project](http://code.google.com/p/netfx/) contains a number of wrapper classes and interfaces to allow just this sort of thing.

Comment: Can you provide names of wrapper classes? I couldn't see documentation at the link.